# Procedure não executa no codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
function renovarEmprestimos($matricula, $livro){
$this->db = $this->load->database('biblioteca', TRUE);
$query = $this->db->query("EXEC J_renovarlivroweb '$matricula', '$livro', '1' ");
//$this->db->last_query();
return $query->result();
}
```

Minha função estava funcional mas agora não consigo mais executar o EXEC chamando a função. Entretanto se chamar $this->db->last_query(); e colocar o EXEC na base do sql funciona certinho. Como posso executar esse exec chamando a função?

Comment: Qual o SGDB que está usando?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: tenta assim, `SELECT J_renovarlivroweb('$matricula', '$livro', '1') `

Comment: @David apresentou o seguinte erro:

Error Number: 195
'J_renovarlivroweb' is not a recognized function name.
SELECT J_renovarlivroweb('14150055', '000000040351', '1')
Filename: models/Biblioteca_model.php
Line Number: 75